# 16-bit assembly string comparison does not work; possible bug?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have another program that does not include the `getUserInput` function. It just compares two strings so I know that `getCheckKey` works correctly. How come this just simply doesn't work? It does not jump to `correct` when the user input matches the string `cupcake`. You can try with:

`nasm -f bin -o cmp-input.bin cmp-input.asm`

`qemu-system-x86_64 cmp-input.bin`

```
ORG 0x7C00
BITS 16


jmp getUserInput                 ; Call function 'getUserInput'

incorrect:
        mov si, invalidKey       ; Set text to SI register
        call printText           ; Call print text function

getUserInput:
        mov si, msg              ; Set greeting text to SI register
        call printText           ; Call print text function
        mov di, inputString      ; set up the string to be read in into di

getKeyLoop:
        mov ah, 0x00             ; Set function 'Reading' for interrupt 16h
        int 0x16                 ; Use 16h interrupt to read next char from keyboard

        mov ah, 0x0e             ; Set char types and colors
        cmp al, 0xD              ; when enter button is pressed...
        je getCheckKey           ; compare the string entered

        int 0x10                 ; otherwise use 10h interrupt to display character
        mov [di], al             ; Move AL to memory of DI address
        inc di                   ; DI += 1; increments the address of DI to store the next character
        jmp getKeyLoop           ; Loop | jump to function 'getKeyLoop'

getCheckKey:                       
        mov byte [di], 0         ; add null terminator to the end of inputString
        mov di, inputString      ; move input string into di
        mov si, password         ; copy password to si for comparison
        CheckKeyLoop:
                mov al, [di]     ; move 1st character or inputString into al
                mov cl, [si]     ; move 1st character of key into cl
                cmp cl, al       ; compare 1st character of both strings
                jne incorrect    ; if they don't match, jump back to getUserInput but print incorrect message first

                cmp al, 0        ; otherwise compare to null terminator
                je correct       ; password match

                inc di           ; otherwise check next char
                inc si           ; check next char
                jmp CheckKeyLoop ; resume the loop

correct:
    mov si, correctnewline
    call printText
        mov si, correctkey

printText:                       ; Function 'printText'
        mov ah, 0x0e             ; Set the text print mode
        mov bh, 0x00             ; Set screen and text parameters
        mov bl, 0x07             ; Set screen and text parameters
printChar:
        mov al, [si]             ; Move character from si (dereferenced) to al

        cmp al, 0                ; If AL = 0...
        je endPrinting           ; Call function 'endPrinting'
                                 ; Else...
        int 0x10                 ; Use 10h interrupt
        add si, 1                ; Move +1 to SI register (inc si)
        jmp printChar            ; Loop back up to 'printChar' function.

endPrinting:                     ; Function 'endPrinting'
        ret                      ; Return



password db "cupcake", 0
msg db " Enter the password: ", 0
invalidKey db " <= Incorrect. Try again..", 13, 10, 0
inputString times 8 db " ", 0
correctnewline db " ", 13, 10, 0
correctkey db " Congratulations!", 13, 10, 0
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: You did not reserve enough space for `inputString`, only a single character. Also your comparison is wrong (it ends on the first zero of `inputString`).

Comment: also never actually terminates the inputString. It checks for 0, but it doesn't put in a 0 at the end (only inistializes it with a space and zero, which gets overwritten.

Comment: @Jester that comparison should work (once a \0  is actually inserted and there is room).  It terminates only if both al and cl are 0.

Comment: I added `inputString:        times 64 db "", 0` but not sure if that adds a null terminator. how would i add that to the end of a string? only on the first attempt, if the password is correct does it work. if i enter the wrong one, then enter, but then the right one, it does not work. why is that?

Comment: You should just `mov byte [di], 0` at `getCheckKey` to put the zero at the end.

Comment: i added that but did not change anything. i noticed that since `cupcake` is 7 letters. if i enter any password up to 7 characters, and then the actual `cupcake`, it works. but if i ever go over that with 8+ characters, i'll never be able to get to `correct` with the right password. i believe that somehow it is overwriting a null terminator but im just not sure how or where.

Comment: Use the [edit] link to update the question with the current code.

Comment: `mov byte [inputString+7], 0` is what i had to do to put a null terminator. but now any characters after `cupcake` still pass ...

Comment: As I said, you should put `mov byte [di], 0` at `getCheckKey` given that `di` is pointing to the next char to store, that is the end of the input. Also, reserving just 8 bytes is not very good either if you want to allow more than that for input. Note that you don't really need to store the input into memory at all, you could be checking it as the user types so then you don't have trouble sizing your buffer.

Comment: thanks. i did modify it to what you mentioned. can you give me an example of how to check it as the user types without reserving space for inputString? thanks